# TLS 1.2 SSL Support

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2, nao-robot

Our Nao Robot is running Python 2.7.3. We have a project that uses IBM Watson cloud services from this robot, and everything has been working fine up til now. IBM increased their security, and now refuses any SSL that is not TLS 1.2.

So all of our requests are failing from the robot. Has anyone else had this issue?  How did you resolve it?  Many web services are moving to this TLS 1.2 requirement, and this old version of Python/OpenSSL does not support it.

Comment: I have this issue as well. I'm unable to upgrade any Python package through pip. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @nyamuk91 We ended up using Watson legacy endpoints created by IBM that did not require TLS 1.2.  

See: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/appsectls.html#watsonprodservices

Answer (score 1):

Python needs to be upgraded, or an intermediate application between the DUT and the cloud can act like a TLS 1 to TLS1.2 converter.